# Cards with different size images in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am using cards to display images. In a row i am showing two or three images. The number of images in a row can change. The sizes of images are different. They don't have same height and width. Because of this, the card height is also changing.

I want to have same height for all the cards even though the image sizes are different. And when we drag screen size the images and cards height and width should change in the same proportion.

I tried fixing the height of each card in to a fixed height in percentages. I played with positioning the cards and images also. But when i drag the screen again the image or the card height is not changing in the same proportion. It should have same card height irrespective of the device or browser or images in the card.

The code is like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-50">card content here</div>
  <div class="col-50">card content here</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-33">card content here</div>
  <div class="col-33">card content here</div>
  <div class="col-33">card content here</div>
</div>
```

Please have a look at the [codepen](http://codepen.io/rajeshwarpatlolla/pen/BNZyMp)

Can some one help me on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I played a bit with your css.

Try adding this code into your css:

```
.col-50, .col-33 {
  display: flex;
}
.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}
.item-avatar, .item.tabs {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.item-body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Prefixed codepen here http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/jPwqMx

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Everything looks good. But if i have small images, the card is not aligning perfectly. I added a css line `width:100%` to '.card' class, and everything look good. If you want to see the above scenario, open `http://codepen.io/rajeshwarpatlolla/pen/pJwEVW` and remove `width:100%` from '.card' class, you will see the issue. If we have `width:100%` to '.card' class, then it looks fine. Please add this line of css to your answer as well as to your codepen. I will accept this answer. Because people might refer this solution, so they should have perfect solution. Finally thanks for your solution.

Comment: And i figured out one more issue. All the cards all the rows are not of equal height. Each row's card heights are same, but the height of cards in a row are changing based on the image height of that row. It could be better if we can make all the cards in all the rows of equal height.

Comment: Good :) I added the width attribute to sample and codepen.

Comment: Can u make all the cards of same height irrespective of the images in all the rows?